# How to style GridViewItem/GridViewItemPresenter in Windows Store apps (Windows 8.1)?

Tags: xaml, gridview, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

I can't seem to find the default **full** style of for `GridViewItem` by **using Edit a copy** function in Blend.

The generated style gives me a `GridViewItemPresenter` and that's it, without any `visual states` or any other elements.

Anyone able to find the style of this `GridViewItemPresenter` anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You find the right code in the below url 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709915.aspx

Comment: The page doesn't give me the default style of `GridViewItemPresenter`, which is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is because by performance reasons you are not supposed to customize internals of [GridViewItemPresenter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.gridviewitempresenter.aspx) too much (well, a part from the public properties from the [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709915.aspx) that @WinitWindowsPhone mentioned).

But.

As described on the same [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709915.aspx) from @WinitWindowsPhone:

> When the GridView's ItemsPanel is not an ItemsWrapGrid (the default) or ItemsStackPanel, the following template is used to show the data items. This template uses a UIElement tree and visual states instead of a GridViewItemPresenter.

```
<!-- Style for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.GridViewItem -->
<Style TargetType="GridViewItem" x:Key="GridViewItemExpanded">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
    <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,2,2"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewItem">
                <Border x:Name="OuterContainer">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="PointerOverBorder"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                     Duration="0"
                                                     To="1" />
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionBackground"
                                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder"
                                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedEarmark"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>

                        ..... Cutting XAML here since it is too huge to post in full, please refer to source page for full source .......

                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid x:Name="ReorderHintContent" Background="Transparent">
                        <Path x:Name="SelectingGlyph" Opacity="0" Data="F1 M133.1,17.9 L137.2,13.2 L144.6,19.6 L156.4,5.8 L161.2,9.9 L145.6,28.4 z" Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckSelectingThemeBrush}" Height="13" Stretch="Fill" Width="15" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,9.5,9.5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
                        <Border x:Name="HintGlyphBorder"
                                Height="40"
                                Width="40"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                Opacity="0"
                                Margin="4">
                            <Path x:Name="HintGlyph" Opacity="0" Data="F1 M133.1,17.9 L137.2,13.2 L144.6,19.6 L156.4,5.8 L161.2,9.9 L145.6,28.4 z" Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckHintThemeBrush}" Height="13" Stretch="Fill"  Width="15" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,5.5,5.5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="ContentContainer">
                            <!-- This extra wrapper grid is necessary because rendertransforms set by the reorder hint animations
                                 will be lost when ContentContainer becomes a LTE -->
                            <Grid x:Name="InnerDragContent">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="PointerOverBorder"
                                           IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                           Opacity="0"
                                           Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                           Margin="1" />
                                <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisual"
                                           IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                           Opacity="0"
                                           StrokeThickness="2"
                                           Stroke="{ThemeResource ListViewItemFocusBorderThemeBrush}" />
                                <Rectangle x:Name="SelectionBackground"
                                           Margin="4"
                                           Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                           Opacity="0" />
                                <Border x:Name="ContentBorder"
                                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                        Margin="4">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                                          ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
                                        <!-- The 'Xg' text simulates the amount of space one line of text will occupy.
                                             In the DataPlaceholder state, the Content is not loaded yet so we
                                             approximate the size of the item using placeholder text. -->
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextBlock"
                                                   Visibility="Collapsed"
                                                   Text="Xg"
                                                   Foreground="{x:Null}"
                                                   Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                   IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                                   AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="PlaceholderRect"
                                                   Visibility="Collapsed"
                                                   Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="MultiArrangeOverlayBackground"
                                                   IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                                   Opacity="0"
                                                   Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="SelectedBorder"
                                           IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                           Opacity="0"
                                           Stroke="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                           StrokeThickness="{ThemeResource GridViewItemSelectedBorderThemeThickness}"
                                           Margin="4"/>
                                <Border x:Name="SelectedCheckMarkOuter"
                                        IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                        Margin="4">
                                    <Grid x:Name="SelectedCheckMark" Opacity="0" Height="40" Width="40">
                                        <Path x:Name="SelectedEarmark" Data="M0,0 L40,0 L40,40 z"  Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}" Stretch="Fill"/>
                                        <Path Data="F1 M133.1,17.9 L137.2,13.2 L144.6,19.6 L156.4,5.8 L161.2,9.9 L145.6,28.4 z" Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckThemeBrush}" Height="13" Stretch="Fill" Width="15" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,5.5,5.5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="MultiArrangeOverlayText"
                                           Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.DragItemsCount}"
                                           Foreground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}"
                                           FontFamily="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"
                                           FontSize="26.667"
                                           IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                           Opacity="0"
                                           TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                           TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
                                           Margin="18,9,0,0" 
                                           AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

So, if your items in `GridView` have not very complex XAML and you don't have a lots of them you probably could go with plain old [WrapGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.wrapgrid.aspx) as a `GridView.ItemsPanel` and use this alternate template above for `GridView.ItemContainerStyle`.